# Need to get users phone numbers for marketing campaign using qr codes

Tags: php, android, iphone, google-analytics, qr-code

I have to build a campaign for a nightclub where they have a qr code and then when the user scans it  10 times they get free entry the next time. i understand how to make qr codes and i am pretty good with mysql databases but i am wondering how i can set it so that i can find the users name or phone number from their handset once they scan the code and land of a page.

i was thinking i could have a url like so embedded into a new qr code every week:

site.com/offer?unique_id=123456

and some how i get the phone number of the user and log it to a mysql database along with the unique id for that week so that each week i can do a:

count * from offers where user_recorded >=10

any help much appreciated?

thanks

Comment: Not sure its possible, your only be able to get user agent, you could make them put there phone number in a field and this field adds to the url of a custom qr code thats generated. Or make them login or add there phonenumber after scanning... also expect savy users to spoof your system

Comment: You can't get their name or number unless they enter it. That's a good thing, or most smart folks would stop using their phone's web-browser.  You might want to assign a cookie when they scan, so that on subsequent scans, they won't have to enter their info again. (btw, don't expect too many folks to give you the correct phone# or name. I know I wouldn't)

Comment: OH. Goody. Websites that can steal a mobile user's phone number so they can get spammed with phone calls as well as unwanted popup ads on the mobile device. Just what the world really needs.

Comment: I don't know if you have thought of this but you would want to change the URL everyday and only let a user claim one checkin per URL, otherwise someone could scan it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is answer for your question but I would use

```
identifierForVendor
```

To get 'unique' device id.
I would save it to the database and I would check how many times this user has scanned the QR barcode. If the value is 10 you can display on the scree 'free entry' and you can set the value back to 0.

Comment: very interesting. but is this used in app development. my only languages of expertise if you could call it that are php, mysql, html, css and some javascript so ideally i would want some way i can integrate this using php or mysql

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to automatically get the user's phone number from just a QR Code. Especially because you can't control the scanner, just the code.

I see two options:

1) As you mention, you can encode

```
http://example.com/offer?unique_id=123456
```

in the QR Code, except that URL would open a mobile site with a form, when users must manually enter their phone number and submit. Because they'll get a benefit from doing that, I guess you won't have much false information.

As mentioned by 323go, you can set a cookie so users have to type their phone number only once. Also, I'd suggest ID to be longer/more complicated than 123456

2) You can create a QR Code which starts an SMS. For example:

```
smsto:987654:123456
```

It will allow users to send an SMS to number 987654 including the ID 123456. You should be able to receive those SMS on the server, parse them and insert to the DB.

That would be more complicated to implement, and it would represent a cost for the user. But at least they wouldn't need to enter their phone number every time.

**As a side note**, consider anyone can share either QR Code to all their friends so everybody gets checked-in that week. A different valid ID per ticket (which can be redeemed only once) would solve that, but that's probably too complicated.